# How to remove the file path from terminal while running a code in visual studio code (mac os )?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur, vscode-code-runner

How to remove the file path from terminal while running a code in visual studio code ?

Im using visual studio code with CodeRunner extension in Mac air M1.
I’ve tried to play with the terminal settings and I couldn't find the one that remove this.
I want that remove the part I marked in red, when i running my program.

[image]

Comment: Those are commands that are being sent by your build/start command to the terminal. What exactly are you trying to achieve and why is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This line is terminal command to compile source code file and run executable.
Soooo, I am not sure if you can remove this. What you can do is write bash script and give your file as an input, but anyway you will pass your file as an argument. What you can do is [configure build task](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/building-your-c-application-with-visual-studio-code/) and run your executable file from terminal, but I'm not sure would you like this way or not.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned this is the gcc (your c compiler) build command. Reason: You build and run your program. This should vanish when you explicit build. And then just run your program without build. Or open Terminal and run your binary with:

```sh
cd /Users/metanpolik/Desktop/VisualProjects
./heyc2
```

But like @UnholySheep wrote, what is the problem? It's just during developing with vs code and should not be a problem.